# P/Invoke Runtime Errors

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am trying to create a managed wrapper around a C++ dll.  When I try to run a test app, I get an error saying loading the dll failed.  This turns out to be a problem with trying to find the CRT.  Copying the CRT to the same directory moves past this problem, but then throws an error saying the application loaded the C Runtime incorrectly (R6034).  A native C++ program has no trouble with either of these issues.

The dll was compiled with vc 2008 - the managed code is compiled in 2010.

The dll has a manifest and I have tried copying the exact version of the CRT into the working directory with the same result as above.

My questions are :

1. Why can the native program load the CRT, but the managed wrapper can't find it?
2. Where could I look for things to try to fix the second error about loading the CRT?
   Could this be because of name mangling, CallingConvention, etc?

C++ Code (I only have the header):

```
class Foo {
public:
   static void startCall(std::string hostname);
}
```

C# Code:

```
    [DllImport("mydll.dll")]
    public static extern void startCall(string hostname );

    public Test()
    {
        string hostname = "";
        startCall(hostname);
    }
```

Comment: 1. Specify versions of all compilers involved. 2. Runtime loaded incorrectly is usually due to manifest issues. 3. Calling convention defaults don't match. Stdcall from managed, cdecl from native. 4. Show the C++ code too.

Comment: Visual Studio versions before VS2010 require their DLL version of the CRT to be deployed in the Windows side-by-side cache.  It is a DLL Hell counter-measure, intended to make the programmer deal with the problem instead of the user.  Turned out that programmers don't like it either so in VS2010 it is again a user problem.  Deploy the proper version of the CRT on the target machine.

Comment: Would different calling conventions really cause the initialization error?

Comment: You need to fix all the errors. Nobody said calling convention error would result in CRT init error.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is impossible to have STL in function interfaces if you want to use the functions in C#.

If you can change the C++ library interface, change it to use char* instead of strings. If you can't write a proxy library which exposes the interface with char* and converts it to std::string and then calls the c++ library which has functions with std::string